# Replace part of javascript string using regex and keep the variable part

Tags: javascript, regex, object

### The problem explained

Given following JS Object:

```
{"name":"a","rotation":2}
```

I am trying to convert all objects with either name: `a, b, c or i` their rotation to 0 if it is currently 2 (or 1 if it is currently 3)

The output for the case above should be:

```
{"name":"a","rotation":0}
```

In my case I am using these objects in a 2 dimensional array like this (but 4x5 instead):

```
[
    [{"name":"a","rotation":2}, {"name":"e","rotation":0}],
    [{"name":"c","rotation":2}, {"name":"j","rotation":2}]
]
```

To save looping trough each dimension I thought it might be easier using a simple regex solution.

This object represents a board state and the goal is checking if this board state is equal to the solution.

I JSON.stringify the board and check if it `===` the solution.

Problem is that if a piece is symmetrical then `rotation0 === rotation2`
and `rotation1 === rotation3`

So to solve this I want to replace all 2's with 0's and 3's with 1's for pieces `a, b, c and i`.

### I tried

Non-capture groups `(?:)` and other methods but no succes.

The solution below shows the problem where in the second parameter I cannot use [abci] to get the letter that was originally there. As I have to replace the whole thing.

```
let obj = '{"name":"b","rotation":2}';

obj.replace(
    /"name":"[abci]","rotation":2/g,
    '"name":"[abci]","rotation":0'
); // Expected: {"name":"b","rotation":0}
```

### Solutions

Using the regex method (see anwser): ±380ms

```
let symetricBoard = JSON.stringify(this.board)
                .replace(/"name":"([abci])","rotation":2/g, '"name":"$1","rotation":0')
                .replace(/"name":"([abci])","rotation":3/g, '"name":"$1","rotation":1');
```

Using the 2d looping: ±14ms

```
let symetricBoard = this.board;

for (let col = 0; col < this.cols; col++) {
    for (let row = 0; row < this.rows; row++) {
        let tile = board[col][row];

        if (tile && "abci".includes(tile.name) && tile.rotation > 1) {
            board[col][row].rotation = (tile.rotation - 2 + 4) % 4;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You would be **much** better off working with objects and not JSON strings representing objects.

Comment: That's a well-formed JSON. Why are you trying to solve the problem like this? I also remind you that JSON properties aren't ordered

Comment: I had found a way to work with the object itself, only this is a simple example of my problem. I have a 2d array where each cell is one of these objects. Therefor I thought it would be much simpler doing it like this.

Comment: You're trying to smash a mosquito with a hammer. I mean, you can but it hurts. If you have an Object, use the right tools.

Comment: Yeah. Just use something like this: `const obj = JSON.parse(str); if (obj.rotation == 2) obj.rotation = 0;` as easy as that

Comment: Now all you need to do is to clarify: Do you have a JSON string, or you indeed have Objects in your 2D array?

Comment: About your regex, instead, it's not working because you need to capture the content of `name` in order to re-use the value. You should pass a callback as the second argument

Comment: I clarified my problem with the 2d array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you **should not** use this snippet in any meaningful scenario, I just try to explain why your regex is not working.

The problem is that when you use the overload `.replace(<regex>, <string>)`, the second parameter is indeed a string, and it has no concept of what `[a|b|c|i]` is. It's just literally that string. The only elements that get parsed in the second argument, when passed as a string, are the tokens that start with `$`. In this way you can reference the first captured group and re-use it:

```js
let obj = '{"name":"b","rotation":2}';

const result = obj.replace(
    /"name":"([abci])","rotation":2/g,
    `"name":"$1","rotation":0`
);

console.log(result)
```

Additionally, there's another overload: `.replace(<regex>, <callback>)`. When you use a callback as the second element, you can just use the first captured group in the regex to reconstruct the initial string:

```js
let obj = '{"name":"b","rotation":2}';

const result = obj.replace(
    /"name":"([abci])","rotation":2/g,
    (_, captured) => `"name":"${captured}","rotation":0`
);

console.log(result)
```

I hope to have satisfied your curiosity. However, I really advise you to don't use any of these, and use `JSON.parse(...)` instead, as stated in the comments above.

### Update

If it's a performance matter, I would still advise you to use `JSON.parse` since it's implemented in C++ (ref. Chrome) and it's thus faster than any other method. You can use a replacer function and make it still faster, since you'll be able to replace values as the string is parsed.

Comment: Yes this was exactly what I was looking for! I did test both methods and you are correct about performance. Looping takes 14ms while regex 380ms